Can Spring Boot Admin display the conditions actuator endpoint?
I'm using the 3.2.3 version of Spring Boot Admin with the Kubernetes Cloud Discovery library. I'm wondering if Spring Boot Admin can display the conditions actuator endpoint of monitored applications and I'm missing some configuration item or it's not an available feature yet.
The /actuator/conditions endpoint is exposed in the monitored application and I can see its results in the browser outside of Spring Boot Admin. But there's no menu option in Spring Boot Admin for the same.

Since version 3.3.3 Spring Boot Admin features a view for conditions.
